# Seldaek/monolog "No such file or directory with DeduplicationHandler"

Tags: php

got error with https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/ for DeduplicationHandler with $deduplicationStore variable.

Stack trace:

```
 
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/dev/application/test-application/var/cache/pro_/monolog_dedup_922a7b2c3485f2fca0b658c7a9e614d9d914a2f5): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/dev/application/test-application/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/DeduplicationHandler.php on line 167
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/dev/application/test-application/bin/console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->run() /var/www/dev/application/test-application/bin/console:30
PHP   3. Monolog\Handler\DeduplicationHandler->close() /var/www/dev/application/test-application/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/BufferHandler.php:0
PHP   4. Monolog\Handler\DeduplicationHandler->flush() /var/www/dev/application/test-application/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/BufferHandler.php:106
PHP   5. Monolog\Handler\DeduplicationHandler->appendRecord() /var/www/dev/application/test-application/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/DeduplicationHandler.php:87
PHP   6. file_put_contents() /var/www/dev/application/test-application/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/DeduplicationHandler.php:167
```

My config for logger:

```
 
monolog:
    handlers:
        detailed_logs:
            type:           service
            id:              detailed_logs.handler
            handler:        nested
        nested:
            type:           stream
            path:           "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:          debug
        fingers_crossed:
            type:           fingers_crossed
            action_level:   critical
            handler:        deduplicated
            buffer_size:    1000
        deduplicated:
            type:           deduplication
            handler:        swift
            buffer_size:    1000
        swift:
            type:         swift_mailer
            from_email:   'error@example.com'
            to_email:     'error@example.com'
            subject:      'An Error Occurred! %%message%%'
            level:        debug
            formatter:    monolog.formatter.html
            content_type: text/html
```

Could you please help me with it?

Comment: I believe it is related to symfony/monolog-bundle 3.2 and symfony 3.3.
For now I disabled the deduplication in monolog-bundle config.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is related to symfony/monolog-bundle 3.2 and symfony 3.3.
The problem is gone after upgrading to symfony/monolog-bundle 3.8 and symfony 3.4.